# How to get Bearer Token from KeyCloak Service using Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, keycloak, rest-assured

I'm trying to find the correct format for obtaining a Bearer Token using Keycloak.

Using Postman, I can obtain the token with no issue.  If I click on `code` and `Java - OkHttp`
I get this snippet:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=amc-front-shop-service&client_secret=18hsudf9-0132-4r6d-804f-b134837d0d29");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://kc.services.enderby.com/auth/realms/FE-SHOP/protocol/openid-connect/token")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

When I try and model the Request in Rest Assured, I get a 400 error but unclear why:

```
 private static RequestSpecification keycloakServiceRequestSpec;
    private static String access_token;

    private void setKeycloakServiceSpecs() {
        keycloakServiceRequestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setContentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public String getAccessToken() {

        setKeycloakServiceSpecs();

        String clientId = "18hsudf9-0132-4r6d-804f-b134837d0d29";
        String clientSecret = "amc-front-shop-service";

        Response response =

        given()
                .auth().preemptive().basic(clientId, clientSecret)
                        .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .formParam("scope", "openid")
        .when()
                .post("https://kc.services.enderby.com/auth/realms/FE-SHOP/protocol/openid-connect/token").
         then().
                assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();

        String json = response.getBody().asString();
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(json);

        access_token =  jsonPath.getString("access_token");

        logger.info("Oauth Token:" +  access_token);

        return access_token;

    }
```

Is it obvious where I am going wrong? Should I pass the key/values into a `.body()` ?

Comment: just a friendly reminder: if these client secrets in your code are real, you should deactivate the client secrets as fast as possible. right now, everybody could use these information to authenticate to your keycloak.

Comment: @Sebu thank you; I have anonymized them all beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing client id/secret and also using basic auth. Also `scope` doesn't seems to be valid for client credentials flow. So try code:

```
        String clientSecret = "18hsudf9-0132-4r6d-804f-b134837d0d29";
        String clientId = "amc-front-shop-service";

        Response response =

        given()
                .auth().preemptive()
                .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .formParam("client_id", clientId)
                .formParam("client_secret", clientSecret)
```